# how to use Jmeter as CI solution

Tags: jmeter, continuous-integration

I have a general question about Jmeter. I am using Jmeter and I want to create Continuous integration solution using Jmeter. The problem is that there are several QA, that each one of them have test plans according his development.  the problem is that if using Jmeter all test plan need to run as one test plan, and for each of test plan to create report, and than manually over each report and check for failed scenarios. So all the handling is much harder than I thought, Jmeter is wonderful solution but how to use it with several test plans, and if I want it to run nightly? and in the mornng to get single report with all test plans that created? Can someone please advise if Jmeter can be solution for CI nightly? is it possible to merge all reports to single report?, each test plan is for unique development, and we will have multiple testplans over time

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at those plugins:

- https://github.com/jmeter-maven-plugin/jmeter-maven-plugin which allows you to fail a build based on presence of errors in load test results which you could mix with https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/AutoStop/
- https://plugins.jenkins.io/performance

Comment: I know but the problem is still multiple JMX files, each is test plan with lots of tests. How to solve the issue that I need to run all JMX and understand what failed, I used Jmeter as functional tests as well, the problem is that multiple testers build tests and how to run all of them together, and with results of all of them in single place

Answer (score 0):

1. JMeter per se is just a load testing tool, you need a [continuous integration server](https://dzone.com/refcardz/continuous-integration-servers). If you don't have one in your company there are several free and open source solutions you can consider like:

   - [Jenkins](https://jenkins.io/)
   - [Buildbot](http://buildbot.net/)
   - [Cruise Control](http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/)

Check out [Jenkins vs. Other Open Source Continuous Integration Servers](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jenkins-vs-other-open-source-continuous-integration-servers) article to learn more about aforementioned tools, see sample build dashboards and commands to kick off a JMeter test.

Comment: Hey Dimitri, we use jenkins. but this is my question: 100 JMX files, lets assume jenknis will run them one by one. How we can see all the results. How it can reflect in the morning in reports? is it create 100 reports? and then manually check one by one? I do not see anywhere what is the outcome of jenkins running 100 jmx files? and in each JMX 30 scenarios, what is the results if one test failed? is it displayed it? and sayed on which JMX?